# Installing drupal 6 from scratch in nginx

Tags: nginx, drupal, drupal-6

So I am trying to install a fresh drupal 6 site on nginx. I have successfully setup the conf files and db. When I try to access `mysite.com` so that I can follow the step by step installation guide, it properly redirects to `mysite.com/install.php` but returns a 403 forbidden error.

On my conf file, I tried to add my IP on the list of allowed IPs:

```
location = /install.php {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow my_ip_address;
    deny all;
}
```

But then, when I try accessing `mysite.com/install.php`, the browser downloads the file instead of running it. What should I do?

I could use drush to install a fresh site, but I wanted to use drupal's install.php file instead (to show a friend how it is done).

Thank you.

---

```
server {
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri;

} # server domain return.

server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    # For drush
    location = /backup {
            deny all;
    }

    # Prevent user from accessing settings.php directly
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/settings.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    ## Replicate the Apache <FilesMatch> directive of Drupal standard
    ## .htaccess. Disable access to any code files. Return a 404 to curtail
    ## information disclosure. Hide also the text files.
    location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|log|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
            return 404;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 403;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1&$args;
            rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # Use an SSH tunnel to access those pages. They shouldn't be visible to
    # external peeping eyes.
    location = /install.php {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location = /update.php {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-cgi/php5.sock;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    ## Drupal 7 generated image handling, i.e., imagecache in core. See:
    ## https://drupal.org/node/371374
    location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Fighting with ImageCache? This little gem is amazing.
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explicit `location = /install.php` overrides any other `location` directives. Except in rare circumstances nginx only matches a request to a single `location`.

Thus, your request gets matched to `location = /install.php`. But, this doesn't contain any of the directives to send the request to php-fpm, so it's handled as a static file and sent to the browser.

There's little point in having this `location` at all. [You're meant to delete the `install.php` file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/19573/10258) after doing the installation or upgrade anyway. So I would just remove those `location`s completely.

Comment: Thank you very much. The explanation behind the solution is highly appreciated as well.